# What is wrong with this proof that the identity map of $S^1$ is nullhomotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have read that the identity map of the unit circle $S^1$ is not nullhomotopic. In fact, I am very new to the subject, so I wonder what is wrong with the following reasoning (that seems to suggest the opposite):

If the identity map $i : S^1 \to S^1$ is nullhomotopic, there exists a homotopy $F : S^1 \times I \to S^1$ with $F(x,0)=x$ and $F(x,1)=k$, for all $x \in S^1$. But this, in other words, just means that $x$ and $k$ can be joined by a path, for any $x \in S^1$ - which is true, since $S^1$ is path connected.

After all, can't we think of a homotopy of two functions $f, g : X \to Y$ as a function that for all $x \in X$, gives us a path between $f(x)$ and $g(y)$?

I wonder where is the contradiction? What I am missing?

Comment: This is a basic logic error. Of course if you assume something false you can conclude anything, so in particular concluding something true does not mean that what you assumed initially is true.

Comment: You've shown that if $S^1$ is contractible, then it's connected. That's true, but so what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true that *if* you have a homotopy $F : X \times [0,1] \to Y$ between $f,g : X \to Y$, *then* for all $x \in X$ this defines a path between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, given by $t \mapsto f(x,t)$.

This is a "if... then..." statement. The converse need to be true. If I give you a map $F : X \times [0,1] \to Y$, and I tell you that for all $x$, $t \mapsto F(x,t)$ is continuous; in other words, I give you a collection of paths from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ for all $x$; does it imply that $F$ itself is continuous? Of course not, and it's rather easy to construct counterexamples.

---

There is an intuitive way to see this for the circle. Imagine your circle is a clock. Let's say you want to find a homotopy between the identity and the map that's constantly equal to 12 o'clock (i.e. $i \in S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = 1 \}$). Then for each point $x$ of the circle you have to a path from $x$ to 12:00. Either you can go through the left part of the circle (going clockwise), or you can go through the right part (going counterclockwise).

It's rather intuitive that if you have a point that just a little bit before 12:00, you will want to go clockwise. And if you're a little bit after 12:00, you will want to go counterclockwise. Since you want this whole thing to be continuous, this will extend all the way to the bottom. But what about 6 o'clock now? How do you choose clockwise or counterclockwise? Whichever way you choose, you will "rip" the circle in half, because just a little bit to the left or to the right you will be going in the other direction. And intuitively, ripping things in half isn't a continuous thing.

---

This isn't a formal proof, obviously. There is a lot of theory to actually prove that it's impossible to find a homotopy between the identity and a constant map, e.g. by showing that the fundamental group of the circle is $\mathbb{Z}$, which isn't trivial. But this is the intuition: if you have to choose *continuously* paths from each $x \in S^1$ to a fixed $x_0 \in S^1$, you will have to "rip" the circle in half sooner or later, and this isn't continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Let us recall the formal definition of a homotopy between $f$ and $g$. Suppose $f,g : X\to Y$ are continuous functions, then a homotopy $H: X \times I \to Y$ is a continuous function such that $H(x,0) = f(x)$ and $H(x,1) = g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. What's the difference between this and what you've mentioned? Your condition isn't enough to satisfy that we get a continuous map. It is true that one can fix a point and vary $t$ to get a path.

So why is the identity map not null-homotopic? One can show that if the identity map on a space is nullhomotopic then the space is contractible, $S^1$ is not contractible, so here's your contradiction. I'm not sure of an easy way to see it without this lemma. One could consider that if $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is nullhomotopic then there exists $\bar{f}: D^2 \to S^1$ which restricted to $S^1$ is $f$, but this gives a retraction of $D^2$ onto its boundary. This uses the fundamental groups of $S^1$ and $D^2$ though.

Comment: @Christoph `:` and `\colon` are *not* equivalent, the spacing is different...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Indeed, that is in fact why I changed the `:` to `\colon`. See for example the [Short Math Guide for $\LaTeX$](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) by the AMS.

Comment: @Christoph What the AMS describes is not at all the norm, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi There is no norm. However, using `\colon` for maps is the recommendation I've heard a lot.

Comment: @Christoph Well, it doesn't really matter. You can change it back if you prefer, I thought you had done the change to get over the character limit for edits.

Comment: \colon looks awful.